# What are the steps to establish an academic journal?

Tags: journals, publishers, journal-workflow

We want to establish a journal. Also I want to add the journal to various indexes. What are the main steps /guide to building an academic journal? What should be done to enter the SCI/SCIe/SSCI index. What is the difference between ISBN, ISSN, DOI numbers. I'm not interesting basic steps like deciding topic, name ,reviewers and editors of journal. It would be nice if you mentioned about the application/reference prices.

*Note:This question might be broad so I can narrow this topic in the direction of your suggestions/comments*

Comment: We have enough journals. It's better quality articles that would be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

This question is indeed rather broad. The specific questions you ask are at once basic and easily researched (you can get basic information about ISSN, ISBN and DOI on Wikipedia, for example) and quite complex (indices have their own rules). This leads me to think that you don't know what you don't know.

I suggest that you contact

- A managing editor or production manager of a journal in your field
- The publication liaison of your learned society
- The acquisitions or new projects person at one of the big journal publishers like Elsevier or Wiley

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think that much more important than technicalities, like DOI, ISSN, etc, is the ability to attract articles that are of interest for your prospective readers. To get authors who can write such articles to publish them in your foreseen journal, you need a broad network in the respective scientific community, and to convince them that there is a need for a new journal, e.g. because a certain niche is being underserved.

I would say that the start of a new journal is rooted in discussing this on relevant conferences, and getting the support of key scientific leaders within the target community.